Want to call multiple apis from one main project
I have following project structure as per below image.

What I want is when I start MainTestAPI project then it should start other Test1, Test2 and Test3 API.
So if MainTestAPI has following URL :
http://localhost:5055

test1 it should work like this
http://localhost:5055/api/Test1
http://localhost:5055/api/Test2

I know I can do that from Visual Studio by setting multiple projects as startup, but I want to set it from some program.cs or startup.cs file ?
I am thinking to use url rewriting, but I am not sure if that works or not.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks


I know I can do that from Visual Studio by setting multiple projects
as startup, but I want to set it from some program.cs or startup.cs
file ?
I am thinking to use url rewriting, but I am not sure if that works or
not.

Well based on your scenario and description, in order to start multiple API projects from a single main project and making them accessible under a common URL, yes you can use a combination of URL rewriting and reverse proxying. This approach allows you to forward requests from the main project to the individual API projects.
One of the most common way is to use YARP (Yet Another Reverse Proxy) library provided by Microsoft to easily set up a reverse proxy in your MainTestAPI project. Add the YARP package to your MainTestAPI project.
Package you need:
Install-Package Yarp.ReverseProxy -Version 2.1.0

You can get it here.
Once you have successfully install the package, then you would require to modify your program.cs file. Please refer to this document.
In addition, each route is matched to a specific path and forwarded to a corresponding cluster and each cluster represents one of the other API projects (Test1, Test2, and Test3), running on different ports (5051, 5052, and 5053).
Note: Please refer to this two official document for sample and implementation details.

Hi Farid, Thanks for help.. Now I have DigitalOcean server account. What I want is to make this working on that server.. so how should I proceed ? Like should I publish all projects differently on different Urls ? OR Like just publish one maintest project API.. Can you please guide me on that

Following both ways it can be achieved. So its would depends on your requirement and scenario. If you have space or memory you could have many project but if there's any limit you could use YERP or IIS reverse proxy features.
